# Using itertools.product in place of double-nested for loop in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, python-itertools, cartesian-product

The following code works, but appears verbose.

```
def gen(l):
    for x in range(l[0]):
        for y in range(l[1]):
            for z in range(l[2]):
                yield [x, y, z]
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(list(gen(l)))

>>>[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

My intention was to cut down on LOC with itertools.product. Here's what I came up with.

```
from itertools import product
def gen(l):
    for x, y, z in product(map(range, l)):
        yield [x, y, z]
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(list(gen(l)))

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Is there a different way to use itertools.product so that there are enough values to unpack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the elements of the `map` iterator to `product` separately with `*`:

```
for x, y, z in product(*map(range, l))
```

Incidentally, with another `map` call, you could save another line, skip the overhead of a Python generator, and do all the work in C:

```
def gen(l):
    return map(list, product(*map(range, l)))
```

Comment: Using the asterisk to separate elements works perfectly, but the second part of your answer returns a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: @CannedSpinach: That shouldn't happen. I did miss that it returns an iterator of tuples instead of lists (which you can [fix](http://ideone.com/X53U7S) with another `map` call), but even the version with tuples [doesn't raise a TypeError](http://ideone.com/eKMOkj).