# Reusable code to iterate along different array dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, list, iteration

Say, I have an N dimensional array `my_array[D1][D2]...[DN]`

For a certain application, like sensitivity analysis, I need to fix a point `p=(d1, d2, ..., dN)` and iterate along each dimension at a time.
The resulting behavior is

```
for x1 in range(0, D1):
    do_something(my_array[x1][d2][d3]...[dN])
for x2 in range(0, D2):
    do_something(my_array[d1][x2][d3]...[dN])
.
.
.
for xN in range(0, DN):
    do_something(my_array[d1][d2][d3]...[xN])
```

As you can see, there are many duplicated code here. How can I reduce the work and write some elegant code instead?

For example, is there any approach to the generation of code similar to the below?

```
for d in range(0, N):
    iterate along the (d+1)th dimension of my_array, denoting the element as x:
        do_something(x)
```

Comment: Why tagged with `c` ?

Comment: Write one additional for loop outside, would it fit your need?

Comment: @Odysseus I used tag "c" because I think this is a general problem and it happens in c, too.

Comment: @PhungDuyPhong Yes, but how? How to iterate through different index positions? I'm dreaming something like ```for i in range(1,N): iterate through index position i of my_array: do_something()```

Comment: You can use itertools instead of nested loops. Please refer the below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38362368/using-itertools-product-in-place-of-double-nested-for-loop-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy.take and do something like the following. Go through the documentation for reference.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html

```
N = len(my_array)
for i in range(N):
  n = len(my_array(i))
  indices = p
  indices[i] = x[i]
  for j in range(n):
     do_something(np.take(my_array,indices))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are d1 d2 d3, but I guess you can do something like this:

```
def get_list_item_by_indexes_list(in_list, indexes_list):
    if len(indexes_list) <= 1:
        return in_list[indexes_list[0]]
    else:
        return get_list_item_by_indexes_list(in_list[indexes_list[0]], indexes_list[1:])

def do_to_each_dimension(multi_list, func, dimensions_lens):
    d0_to_dN_list = [l - 1 for l in dimensions_lens] # I dont know what is it
    for dimension_index in range(0, len(dimensions_lens)):
        dimension_len = dimensions_lens[dimension_index]
        for x in range(0, dimension_len):
            curr_d0_to_dN_list = d0_to_dN_list.copy()
            curr_d0_to_dN_list[dimension_index] = x
            func(get_list_item_by_indexes_list(multi_list, curr_d0_to_dN_list))


def do_something(n):
    print(n)

dimensions_lens = [3, 5]
my_array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    ]

do_to_each_dimension(my_array, do_something, dimensions_lens)
```

#### Output:

```
5  10  15  11  12  13  14  15
```

This code iterates through the last column and the last row of a 2d array.

Now, to iterate through the last line of each dimension of 3d array:

```
dimensions_lens = [2, 4, 3]
my_array = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3], 
        [4, 5, 6], 
        [7, 8, 9], 
        [10, 11, 12]
        ], 
    [
        [13, 14, 15], 
        [16, 17, 18], 
        [19, 20, 21], 
        [22, 23, 24]
        ], 
    ]

do_to_each_dimension(my_array, do_something, dimensions_lens)
```

#### Output:

```
12  24  15  18  21  24  22  23  24
```

(Note: don't use zero-length dimensions with this code)

Answer (score 0):

You could mess with the string representation of your array access (`my_arr[d1][d2]...[dN]`) and [`eval`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) that afterwards to get the values you want. This is fairly "hacky", but it will work on arrays with arbitrary dimensions and allows you to supply the indices as a list while handling the nested array access under the hood, allowing for a clean double for loop .

```py
def access_at(arr, point):
    # build 'arr[p1][p2]...[pN]'
    access_str = 'arr' + ''.join([f'[{p}]' for p in point])
    return eval(access_str)
```

Using this access method is pretty straight forward:

```py
p = [p1, ..., pN]
D = [D1, ..., DN]
for i in range(N):
    # deep copy p
    pt = p[:]
    for x in range(D[i]):
        pt[i] = x
        do_something(access_at(my_array, pt))
```